# how to check mobile number exits in real world or not using c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Is it possible to check the mobile number exits or not using C# code
So the we can check the mobile number exits in real world
and is current in use

Comment: I *highly doubt* any particular language has *native* functionality which would accomplish this.  But you may look for some APIs exposed by mobile phone providers.

Comment: You could check if a mobile number is valid. In order to do so, you have to define a pattern. I am not aware of a general pattern for this. Regarding if a mobile is in use or not, I think that this is impossible to be known.

Comment: You might want to send an sms using some online service with a verification code to be sure!

Comment: i till now not find any api for this if any one knows please help and giving me a link of that api